# Thrust: multiple definition of b40c_thrust::vote_reduction

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, thrust

I'm using Cuda 5.0 in separate compilation mode.
In

```
thrust/system/cuda/detail/detail/b40c/kernel_utils.h
```

there is this definition

```
__shared__ int vote_reduction[B40C_WARP_THREADS];
```

The linker complains of multiple definition of `vote_reduction`.

What is the workaround for this?

**Added: Code to reproduce the problem**

Thrust version: 100600

iterator.h

```
#pragma once
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

struct Unary_Op
{
    __host__ __device__ int operator()(const int index) const;
};

int iterates(int start, int end);
```

iterator.cu

```
#include "iterator.h"

__host__ __device__ int Unary_Op::operator()(const int index) const
{
    return index;
}

int iterates(int start, int end)
{
    thrust::counting_iterator<int> first(start);
    thrust::counting_iterator<int> last = first + end;

    Unary_Op unary_op = Unary_Op();
    thrust::plus<int> binary_op;
    int init = 0;

    int sum = thrust::transform_reduce(first, last, unary_op, init, binary_op);

    return sum;
}
```

calculation.h

```
#include "iterator.h"

int compute();
```

calculation.cu

```
#include "calculation.h"

int compute()
{
    return iterates(0,10);
}
```

main.cu

```
#include "calculation.h"

int main()
{
    compute();
    return 0;
}
```

compilation command (NSight)

```
Building file: ../calculation.cu
Invoking: NVCC Compiler
nvcc -G -g -O0 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -odir "" -M -o "calculation.d" "../calculation.cu"
nvcc --device-c -G -O0 -g -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20  -x cu -o  "calculation.o" "../calculation.cu"

Building file: ../iterator.cu
Invoking: NVCC Compiler
nvcc -G -g -O0 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -odir "" -M -o "iterator.d" "../iterator.cu"
nvcc --device-c -G -O0 -g -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20  -x cu -o  "iterator.o" "../iterator.cu"

Building file: ../main.cu
Invoking: NVCC Compiler
nvcc -G -g -O0 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -odir "" -M -o "main.d" "../main.cu"
nvcc --device-c -G -O0 -g -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20  -x cu -o  "main.o" "../main.cu"

Invoking: NVCC Linker
nvcc --relocatable-device-code=true -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -link -o  "testt"  ./calculation.o ./iterator.o ./main.o   
nvlink error   : Multiple definitions of '_ZN6thrust6system4cuda6detail6detail11b40c_thrust14vote_reductionE'
nvlink error   : Multiple definitions of '_ZN6thrust6system4cuda6detail6detail11b40c_thrust14vote_reductionE'
make: *** [tt] Error 255
```

Comment: can you provide a simple complete example that reproduces the error message along with the nvcc command line?

Comment: If you build an ordinary project instead of a relocatable device code project, does the error go away?  by the way you may want to build in release mode instead of debug.  Thrust is [not compatible](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/Debugging) with `-G`.  Did you upgrade thrust to 1.6 (that is not the version that ships with with cuda 5)?

Comment: @RobertCrovella If by ordinary project, you mean "Whole program compilation", the compiler complains that "external call are not supported". Yes, I upgraded the shipped thrust to 1.6.

Comment: I meant could you build the code you posted into this question as a whole program compilation project, not your original project.  I can compile the code above with an ordinary sequence of compile commands and get a functional program.  At the moment I don't have access to all my development systems so I don't have an nsight-ready machine.  But if I build all the .cu files with nvcc -c and then link it all together, it works fine with no errors.  I was asking if you could do the same because I think it will focus the question on the relocatable code generation, which is my suspicion.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I tried "whole program compilation" in release mode, with the posted code, and everything worked, both compilation and linking. Good insight.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem with the version of thrust that ships with CUDA 5.  With thrust v1.6 I see other issues.  Which gcc compiler version are you using?  What is your OS?

Comment: OK I'm able to reproduce the problem with CentOS 6.2 (gcc 4.4.6)  If you can revert to thrust 1.5.3 that ships with CUDA 5, the issue (at least for the example posted in this question) should go away.

Comment: I was also able to make the issue go away by advancing thrust to the latest v1.7 development (master) branch.

Comment: @RobertCrovella My environnement is: gcc version 4.4.3, nvcc 5.0 v0.2.1221, Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS. I will try with thrust v1.7.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I tried with thrust v1.7 and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appeared to be a bug or issue with separate compilation that was specific to the version of thrust that shipped in the CUDA 5.x toolkit. Upgrading or downgrading to thrust 1.5.3 or thrust 1.7 appears to have solved the problem

[This answer has been assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get the question off the unanswered question list]